# Changing order of documents in mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I am fooling around with databases for the first time using mongoose.js, but I can't figure out something that to me seems like pretty basic functionality.
I want to put a specific document one position up in the database, to update the order in which the documents are loaded when I fetch them all.
I can't find some build-in method for this except for maybe .sort(), but that would mean I have to keep track of the indexes of each instance, change them accordingly when I want to change the order and then sort the database based on that new property, this seems like reinventing the wheel to me.

Am i simply overlooking some basic concept about databases and am I not supposed to do this? Or am I missing the function I'm looking for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MongoDB doesn't provide any ability to explicitly modify the natural order of the documents in a collection and may move docs around in the collection as they are updated.

If you want your docs returned in a specific order, the docs must contain a field you can sort on to put them in that order.  For the sort to be performant, you typically need to also create an index on that field.

Answer (score 1):

You can use a bypass to achieve
this behavior:

Let say you have chat rooms and you want the room who was the latest to be updated will be at the top of the list.

You can create a wrapper Document which will contain array of room sub documents

```js
let RoomsSchema = Schema({
   isActive: { type: Boolean },
   name: { type: String, required: true },
   ownerId:{type: String},
   participants: { type: Array },
   messages: [MessageSchema],
   updateTime: { type: Date },
   creationTime: { type: Date },
}, { versionKey: false });

let MainDoc = Schema({
   rooms:[RoomsSchema]
});
```

Then let say you'll have a schema function to add message, something as follows:

```js
MainDoc.statics.ADD_Message = async function (roomId, message) {
    let main = await this.findOne({});
    let room = await main.rooms.id(roomId);
    room.messages.push(message);
    let roomIdx = main.rooms.findIndex(x => x._id == room._id);

    if (roomIdx > -1) {
        main.rooms.splice(roomIdx, 1);
        main.rooms=[room,...main.rooms];
     }
     return main.save();
};
```